# Как сделать перенаправление TCP соединения с одного порта на несколько?

Tags: linux, portforwarding

В `socat` есть команда `fork`, которая перенаправляет на указанный адрес. А можно ли перенаправить одно входящее соединения на не один, а на несколько портов? Если не с `socat`, то может ещё есть варианты?

Comment: соединение по протоколу tcp подразумевает обмен пакетами по протоколу ip. если на один и тот же ip-запрос отправитель получит несколько отличающихся (валидных) ответов, то обработан будет первый валидный, остальные же будут отброшены как «информационный мусор». так что начинать вам имеет смысл не с socat или чего-то подобного, а с собственной реализации отправителя, который будет в нарушение соответствующего rfc обрабатывать и ответы-дубликаты, создавая несколько tcp-сессий вместо одной

Comment: собственно реализация протокола tcp находится, емнип, непосредственно в программе linux. так что вам придётся писать собственную реализацию этого протокола.

Comment: Цели REDIRECT и DNAT в iptables принимают port range в качестве destination. Что это, как оно точно работает и как это вообще можно использовать — вопрос к вам.

Comment: Видимо, задача, описанная в вопросе, не имеет простого решения. Может, её можно сформулировать по другому? например, может, вам нужно не tcp соединение "расщепить", а поможет банальный proxy?

Comment: Читайте про балансировщики нагрузки, они именно этим и занимались во времена apache 2.0.

Comment: Благодарю всех за комментарии. Скорее всего да, тут только кастомный "прокси-разветвитель". Его и написал )

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю вопрос, можно это сделать с помощью `tee` и `bash`'евских перенаправлений в процесс как-то так:

```
socat -u TCP4-LISTEN:1024 - | tee >(socat -u - TCP4:localhost:1025) >(socat -u - TCP4:localhost:1026)
```

Какую-то более сложную логику будет проще набросать на `perl`/`python`.

Comment: Я пробовал данный вариант. К сожалению это работает только в одну сторону - ответ от конечного сокета придёт в sockat и всё, другая сторона его не получит. Решил вопрос своим сервером на плюсах